# Weighted (co)limit, perhaps incomplete specification of the natural bijection

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, limits-colimits, functors

I'm trying to understand the notion of weighted colimit in as detail as possible. [Here](https://books.google.cz/books?id=6xpvAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=%22Here+we+reversed+the+variance+of+the+constant+functor%22&source=bl&ots=HdMc-zbu2X&sig=Ywgv7egXMR8H_1zxDw--w3jLGyg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8gOLP3YXRAhVMBMAKHaw0C6oQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Here%20we%20reversed%20the%20variance%20of%20the%20constant%20functor%22&f=false) is a good explanation. However in the first displayed formula on page 100 starting with $\cal M$, the isomorphisms is too "general" for me. I would expect that the isomorphism works by pre-composition with an arrow $m\to $lim$F$ from the set on the l.h.s. and the limit cone, and $\cong$ is thus *not* an arbitrary natural
isomorphism. However, this property of $\cong$ in the first displayed formula mentioned is never stated on pages 99 nor 100. Am I right with this?
Also this more general notion of $\cong$ *is* possible when weighted limit is considered instead of the usual one, even if $W$ is equal to *,and thus the weighted limit weighted by * may have other $\cong$ then the usual limit?
Or Am I completely wrong and the $\cong$ is always unique?

Answer (score 2):

All you need here is Yoneda. The limit $\ell$ of $F$ weighted by $W$ is a representation of the functor of $W$-weighted cones; the representation is uniquely determined by where it sends the identity map of the limit, which is a particular natural transformation from $W$ to $\mathrm{Hom}(\ell,F)$. When $W$ is the terminal functor and you're calculating an ordinary limit, this is a point of the latter homs, which is to say a natural transformation from $\ell$ to $F$, that is, the usual limit cone over $F$ you're looking for. Thus the isomorphism is here, and was in the case of ordinary limits, an arbitrary natural isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, but when we're calculating an ordinary limit, this is a point of the latter homs, which is to say a natural transformation from ℓ to F, but that natural transformation from ℓ to F should be a *universal one*. How do we secure by choosing an element in Hom(ℓ,F) that we not only have a natural transformation from ℓ to F but also a universal one?

Comment: It's universal because it gives a natural isomorphism between homs into $\ell$ and cones over $F$, not just an arbitrary natural transformation.